# Using gawk to alter columns after a line identifier

Tags: awk, gawk, math

I have multiple drawing files in the format detailed below. I need to increase the value of a number in the area of the file below after the line **BO**. All values (in the sample below) that are 14.00 need to be increased by 1 to 15.00. In this case, the 5 lines below **BO** would become 15.00. I can see that `$4+1` will increase the value, however, the two decimal places are missing.

I can see that gawk allows for C like expressions so would be a solution. What I cannot understand is how to detect the **BO** record and then manipulate the fields until **`EN`** is reached.

Any advice on how this could be achieved is appreciated.

Thank you.

```
AK
  v       0.00u      0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        398.56       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        398.56      50.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00      50.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
BO
  v      25.00o     18.75      14.00
  v      75.00o     18.75      14.00
  v     323.56o     18.75      14.00
  v     373.56o     18.75      14.00
EN
```

Comment: It seems to me that `sed '/^BO/,/^EN/s/ 14\.00/ 15.00/g'` would be enough with those requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved through the use of a very simple state-machine:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '/^[A-Z][A-Z]/ && !/^BO/ { flag=0 } /^BO/ { flag=1 } flag == 1 && NF == 4 { $4 = sprintf("%.2f", 1+$4) } { print }' file
AK
  v       0.00u      0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        398.56       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        398.56      50.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00      50.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
BO
v       25.00o  18.75   15.00
v       75.00o  18.75   15.00
v       323.56o 18.75   15.00
v       373.56o 18.75   15.00
EN
```

The script does nothing but pass along the input to the output until it hits the line starting with `BO`, then it sets `flag` to 1.

If `flag` is 1 and the current line contains four columns, the fourth column is reformatted using `sprintf()` and `1+$4`.  The format specification `%.2f` means "a floating point value with two decimal places".

If something other than `BO` is found at the start of the line, `flag` is reset to zero.

The padding between the columns are changed on the output lines where a modification has been made.  This is because `awk` splits the fields on whitespaces and then rejoins them using `OFS` (set to a tab character here) when the output happens.

To get exactly the same output format as the input, you may do something like

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '/^[A-Z][A-Z]/ && !/^BO/ { flag=0 } /^BO/ { flag=1 } flag == 1 && NF == 4 { printf("%3s %11s%10.2f %10.2f\n", $1,$2,$3,1+$4); next } { print }' file
AK
  v       0.00u      0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        398.56       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        398.56      50.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00      50.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
BO
  v      25.00o     18.75      15.00
  v      75.00o     18.75      15.00
  v     323.56o     18.75      15.00
  v     373.56o     18.75      15.00
EN
```

Comment: Thank you Kusalananda for the detailed explanation. I have found an example (frustratingly) where **BO** is in the middle of a file and has a block of four tabs in a **KO** after it. I will have a go at changing the flag as this solution does work on the files of this structure but not in general. Your solution considers the need for calculation (sometimes the value is 22.00). As I require a mathematical function the `sed` example by @Stéphane would work but I need to sort the files initially into groups.

Comment: I need to do something like this (still not working I think there is an order problem and the regex is cancelling the **BO** check) so a little more reading... `awk -v OFS="\t" '/^BO/ { flag=1 };/^[A-Z][A-Z]/ {flag=0} flag == 1 && NF == 4 { printf("%3s %11s%10.2f %10.2f\n", $1,$2,$3,1+$4); next } { print }'`

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for your advice.

`awk -v OFS="\t" '/^[A-Z][A-Z]/ {flag=0}; /^BO/ { flag=1 } flag == 1 && NF == 4 { printf("%3s %11s%10.2f %10.2f\n", $1,$2,$3,1+$4); next } { print }'`

Comment: @2CV375 Yes, that's one way of doing it, definitely. I will update the answer with my take no it.